# Generalization of the well-known commutator relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Denote $$G^1 = G, G^2 = [G,G], G^3 = [G,G,G] = [[G,G],G], \ldots, G^k = [G^{k-1},G].$$

Suppose we consider a commutators of $n$ copies of $G$ that are not neccesarily left associated. For example if $n=5$, we might have something like
$[[G,G], [G,G], G]$. We refer to such an object as a commutator of **weight** $5$.

The following result is well-known.

> **Theorem.** Every weight $n$ commutator of copies of $G$ is contained in $G^n$.

Now let us generalise this situation and for arbitrary subgroups $A_1,\ldots A_n$ we define analogously the commutator of weight $n$. For example for $n=5$ we can consider
$[[A_1,A_2],[A_3,A_4,A_5]]$ or $[[A_1,A_2],[A_3,A_4],A_5]$ .

> **My question.**  Is it true again that every such commutator of weight
>   $n$ belongs to the left-associated commutator $[A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n]$?

I suspect that in general the answer is no. So I am also interesting when the answer is yes.

Comment: You'll get a counterexample in $S_3$ if you take $A_1=A_2=\langle (12)\rangle$, $A_3=\langle (123)\rangle$ as $[A_1,A_2, A_3]=1$ but $[A_1,[A_2,A_3]]=A_3$.

Comment: Thank you, @ancientmathematician this is really demonstrative example.

Comment: But I'd like to know the answer to your final sentence!

Comment: I want to know this answer too)

Comment: Maybe it's true when all $A_i$ are normal subgroups? indeed Hall's formula then implies $[A,[B,C]]\subset [B,[C,A]][C,[A,B]]$ for all normal subgroups $A,B,C$, if I'm correct.